# Where is the configuration file for OpenSSH server?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to disable password authentication at my SSH server. I found the client config file at `ssh_config`, but I can't find the server's configuration file. [`man ssh_config(5)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5) does not appear to tell us what the server uses.

Where is the server's configuration file?

Comment: The server is sshd

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `sshd_config.conf`

Comment: @Zacharee1 - the man page says `ssh_config` is for clients. What does the server use for its configuration?

Comment: You have to do `man sshd_config`

Comment: @Zacharee1 - I did. That's how I know `ssh_config` is for the clients.

Comment: `sshd_config` is supposed to be the server configuration.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - OK, thanks. It definitely does not appear to be so on an install I performed recently. On the server, in `/usr/local/etc/ssh_config`, I added `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `PasswordAuthentication no` (and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` for good measure). On a different client, with `-v`, I get `debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received` and then `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive`. In my mind's eye, `password` should not be present. I wish the damn man pages were accurate so I could get authoritative information...

Comment: @Zacharee1 - yeah, the server was not using `ssh_config` by default. When I passed the `-f <file>` option (and `-t` to test it), the server refused to start with ***`ssh_config: bad configuration option: HostName`***.

Comment: I don't think the `N` is supposed to be capitalized in `HostName`

Comment: Thanks  Zacharee1. According to the man page, it is correct. Its like I said... I wish the damn man pages were accurate. I prefer to RTFM and avoid going to the outside world.

Comment: What OS are you using? When I do `man sshd_config` the second line tells me exactly where `sshd_config` is located, and according to *my* documentation`'HostName` *is* invalid, it does not exist in the man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in some comments, `ssh_config` is for (default) client configuration, but server configuration is done in `sshd_config`, typically in `/etc/ssh` on most *NIX systems, but is `/etc/sshd_config` in the case of MacOS X and perhaps other systems.

As for disabling password authentication, look at the option `PasswordAuthentication` and set it to `no`; the default is typically `yes`.  Also look at other options including `PermitRootLogin` which, IMO, should be set to `no` (or at least `without-password`), and `UsePAM` which can affect password-based authentication as well.